# Use the 'sed' command to find a pattern and then replace everything after that using Python

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression, python

I have a file like this on my Linux system, and I want it changed to the output below using a Python script.

*1_file_name=xyz.vps*:

```
input0_bpp=8
input0_is_padding_enable=0
input0_task0_file_name=${MY_DIR}/validation/suites/pole1/test_data/cam_1024x512.bin
output0_bpp=8
output0_is_padding_enable=0
output0_task0_file_name=${MY_DIR}/validation/suites/pole1/test_data/cam_1024x512.bin
```

I want my *output* file (*1_file_name=xyz.vps*) to be like this:

```
input0_bpp=8
input0_is_padding_enable=0
input0_task0_file_name=cam_1024x512.bin
output0_bpp=8
output0_is_padding_enable=0
output0_task0_file_name=cam_1024x512.bin
```

Comment: Why do you need python in this? And, if you are using python, why would you need sed? Can't you just use one tool? both sed and python are perfectly capable of doing the entire thing.

Comment: What is the actual file name? `xyz.vps` or `1_file_name=xyz.vps`? If the former (the most likely), what is `1_file_name`? It isn't referenced anywhere.

Comment: The title is so very misleading.... search for a pattern using sed but do a replacement using python :-/

Answer (score 4):

It seems you just need to get rid of the filepath.

```
sed -e 's,file_name=.*/,file_name=,'  < file > newfile
```

should do the trick... it takes, on each line containing `file_name=.../...`, the whole portion between the `=` and the *last* `/` out of the line.

If you want to edit "in place", and use GNU `sed`, you can:

```
sed -i -e 's,file_name=.*/,file_name=,' file # This modifies the file. Back it up first!
```

Comment: It's unlikely but theoretically possible that a value on the right hand side of the first `=` on a line contains the string `file_name=.../...`, in which case it would be modified in error. You may guard against this by matching no `=` before `file_name`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: it will only replace the first occurence of this on the line, so whatever is on the right side of it, if it contains 1 or more "/" will be deleted (up to the last "/") as it is expected to be a dirpath to be discarded. I hope it does what the OP wants, but indeed it may need some additionnal safeguards in case other lines containing "file_name=..." are of a different kind and not to be touched

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` you can print two fields, first and last in this case, when the line has `{MY_DIR}` if previously you set `FS` as `[/=]`.

```bsh
$ awk -v FS='[/=]' -v OFS='=' '/{MY_DIR}/ {print $1, $NF;next} 1' file > outputfile
input0_bpp=8
input0_is_padding_enable=0
input0_task0_file_name=cam_1024x512.bin
output0_bpp=8
output0_is_padding_enable=0
output0_task0_file_name=cam_1024x512.bin
```

The condition here is  `/{MY_DIR}/` and the action is `{print $1, $NF;next}`. The default action in `awk` is `print`, here `1` at the end.
Finally  the result is saved in `outputfile` file.

Comment: The sentence makes sense, but only after reading it 6-7 times. Can you fix it? You can [edit your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/632019/edit).

Comment: Ok. Added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not generally recommended, here's a shell loop to solve the issue:

```bsh
while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
    case $key in (*_file_name) value=$( basename "$value" ); esac
    printf '%s=%s\n' "$key" "$value"
done <file
```

For each line in the file called `file`, this reads the bit before the `=` into the `key` variable, and everything after the `=` into the variable `value`.

If the `$key` value ends with the string `_file_name`, the value is modified by the `basename` utility, which returns only the filename portion of the pathname in its argument.  If you don't have pathnames ending with `/`, then you may use `${value##*/}` instead of the whole command substitution.

The `printf` call then outputs the key with its possibly modified value, with a `=` in-between.

---

With `sed`:

```bsh
sed 's|^\([^=]*_file_name=\).*/|\1|' file
```

On each line where the given regular expression matches, this removes the bit between the first `=` and the last `/` characters.  This would likely do the wrong thing if the pathname after the `=` was a pathname for a directory written with a `/` at the end.

---

`awk` could be use like so:

```bsh
awk -F '=' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $1 ~ /^[^=]*_file_name$/ { sub("=.*/", "=", $0) }; 1' file
```

This is more or less a straight translation of the initial shell loop into an `awk` program.

Reading lines with `=`-delimited fields, the `sub()` is triggered whenever the first field matches a similar expression as used in the `sed` variation above.  The `sub()` call removes everything from the first `=` on the line, up to and including the final `/`.

As with the `sed` variation, this would possibly do the wrong thing (remove the whole pathname) if the pathname was that of a directory, written with a trailing `/`.